# ASP.NET masterpage public variables error

Tags: asp.net

I have public variable 'MessagePlaceholder' on MasterPage and a Class that accesses this property like that setting it's value to string from getMessage();

```
((HttpContext.Current.Handler as System.Web.UI.Page).Master as MasterPage).MessagePlaceholder = getMessage();
```

which gives me an error like this one

Error   3   'System.Web.UI.MasterPage' does not contain a definition for 'MessagePlaceholder' and no extension method 'MessagePlaceholder' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Web.UI.MasterPage' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

What should i do ?

Comment: Is `MasterPage` the type name of your specific master page?

Comment: @Graham Clark, i don't have specific type for master page, all done on page ( not code behind )

Comment: no, I mean you obviously have a Master Page file - what is it called?

Comment: @Graham Clark, MasterPage without code behind

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have added the variable MessagePlaceHolder in your masterpage. That means you have extended the functionality of a standard Masterpage.

You have to cast the Master property to your type of the Masterpage.

```
((MyMasterClass)((Page)HttpContext.Current.Handler).Master).MessagePlaceHolder = getMessage();
```

or in VB.Net

```
DirectCast(DirectCast(HttpContext.Current.Handler, Page).Master, MyMasterClass).MessagePlaceHolder = getMessage()
```

Comment: What the type would be ? I did not define a Class named MyMasterClass or anything else

Comment: Whats the type of your masterpage? Look in the master directive at the inherits property.
F.e.: <%@ Master Language="VB" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeBehind="ERP.Master.vb" Inherits="ERP.ERPMaster" %>
In this example ERP.ERPMaster is the type of my Masterpage.

Comment: i don't have code behind. Is there any way to make this without rewriting MasterPage with code behind ?